# Feed arrays into trend function in VBA, results wrong

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

Can anybody advise why the excel trend function (in VBA) does not give a result when working with an array of the **type variant** and why it gives a wrong result when working with an **Dim arr() as Integer** type of array?

I try to feed two arrays with y and x values into the Excel trend function to get a new y value for a new x value. However, the resulting values are wrong. It has something to do with passing a variant/integer array into the excel function.

I retrieve a matrix via sql that holds day values in one column and number values in another column (there are multiple columns with number values, but this is not the problem here so I used only one column of number values as an example).

```html
FMV_Day FMV_10000
365      65
548      63
730      61
913      59
1095     57
1278     55
1460     53
1643     51
1825     49
365      65
548      63
```

I use VBA to store the values from the sql query in an array. One array for the days, one array for the number values. The arrays are declared as  "Dim percentages() As Integer Dim days() As Integer". This produces results, but they are way off. When I declare the arrays as "Dim values As Variant" etc. the script wont run and result the error message:
"Unable to get Trend property of Worksheet function class." The key part of the script looks as follows...

```
For Each element In columns
    If element = "Day" Then

        If Not lrs1.EOF Then

            lrs1.MoveFirst   'Ensure we begin on the first row

            iCounter = 0
            ReDim days(intArraySize) 'Need to size the array

            Do Until lrs1.EOF
                days(iCounter) = lrs1.Fields("FMV_" & mileage_element)
                'Debug.Print "Item: "; iCounter & " " & days(iCounter)
                iCounter = iCounter + 1
                lrs1.MoveNext
            Loop

        End If

    lrs1.MoveFirst

    ElseIf element = element_given Then
        If Not lrs1.EOF Then

            lrs1.MoveFirst   'Ensure we begin on the first row

            iCounter = 0
            ReDim values(intArraySize) 'Need to size the array

            Do Until lrs1.EOF
                values(iCounter) = lrs1.Fields("FMV_" & element)
                'Debug.Print "Item: "; iCounter & " " & values(iCounter)
                iCounter = iCounter + 1
                lrs1.MoveNext
            Loop

        End If
    End If
Next element
fnc_FMV = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(values, days, Array(liAge))(1)
```

Here is one example for the erroneous results that I get when working with an array that was defines as an Integer array:

```html
Days-Array:            365, 548, 730, 913, 1095, 1278, 1460, 1643, 1825
Values-Array:          65, 63, 61, 58, 56, 54, 52, 50, 48
Age                    126 
Result from Trend_fnc  41.7662243865297
```

The **correct result** for the above example would be **67.75165**. This is derived by me through simply using the same values from the days and values array in an Excel spread sheet and applying the trend function.

EDITEDITEDIT

I am not using Excel. I am exclusively using access to solve this problem, since everything else of this rather large script is in access and I am querying a database.

Ok I tried your suggestion and changed the following within the both Do loops from above:

```
ReDim days(1 To intArraySize, 1 To 1)
```

and

```
ReDim value(1 To intArraySize, 1 To 1)
```

I added another dimension for the array. Don't know what this should help... anyway, now I am getting a sub script out of range error for line

```
days(iCounter) = lrs1.Fields("FMV_" & mileage_element)
```

EDIT2
I used

```html
Debug.Print days(0) & ", " & days(1) & ", " & days(2) & ", " & days(3) & ", " & days(4) & ", " & days(5) & ", " & days(6) & ", " & days(7) & ", " & days(8) 
Debug.Print values(0) & ", " & values(1) & ", " & values(2) & ", " & values(3) & ", " & values(4) & ", " & values(5) & ", " & values(6) & ", " & values(7) & ", " & values(8)
```

to make sure the values I retrieve via sql are correct and correctly put into the array. All the inputs are correct, but the trend function messes up the result. I believe it has something to do with the datatype of the arrays that go into the trend function. I believe that if I would use a Variant datatype this error would not happen, but I get another error, when I try to enter a Variant array into the trend function.
"Unable to get Trend property of Worksheet function class."

Comment: I can't replicate that (though I think your result should be 67.75165 based on those values) - I get the same result in VBA as in the cell. Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am building this code in Access, I am not using Excel, I am just using the excel function.. Both Excel and Access are version 2010

Comment: You are right, I miscalculated the example. The true value should be 67.75165

Answer (score 1):

So, with some external help I found the solution.
The arrays I Redim'ed were one slot too large. I needed nine slots and dim'ed for 9, but since arrays start at 0 it actually had 10 slots. The empty slot was automatically filled with a zero which subsequently altered the calculation. In the above code the following needs to be changed:

```
            ReDim days(intArraySize-1) 'Need to size the array

            ReDim percentages(intArraySize-1) 'Need to size the array
```

The minus one is the solution.
This took me 2 and a half days. WTF.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Moral of the story: specify both lower and upper bound when Redim'ing eg `ReDim days(1 to intArraySize)` or `ReDim days(0 to intArraySize - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data, I found the trendline to be y = -0.01178x + 69.23604

This means that at x=126, y = 67.75164...

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrendAnalysis()

  Dim vDays As Variant
  Dim vValues As Variant
  Dim newX As Variant

  newX = Array(126)

  vDays = Array(365, 548, 730, 913, 1095, 1278, 1460, 1643, 1825)
  vValues = Array(65, 63, 61, 58, 56, 54, 52, 50, 48)

  Dim Test As Variant
  Test = WorksheetFunction.Trend(vValues, vDays, newX, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: You are right, I miscalculated the example. The true value should be 67.75165. Will try your way of defining the arrays.

Comment: After taking a look at dePatinkin's answer I realized the data does not have to be in the format I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the `Trend` result for me as well is **67.75**, and I get the same result with integer arrays and variant ones.

The thing is, you have to provide arrays for the first three parameters (Known_ys, Known_xs, New_xs). The result is also a Variant array with the same items count as the New_xs array (or if not provided the Known_xs array).

This shows both Integer and Variant provided arrays results:

```
Sub useTrend()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant
    Dim r As Variant
    Dim xi(8) As Integer
    Dim yi(8) As Integer
    Dim ri As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    x = Array(365, 548, 730, 913, 1095, 1278, 1460, 1643, 1825)
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        xi(i) = x(i)
    Next
    y = Array(65, 63, 61, 58, 56, 54, 52, 50, 48)
    For i = 0 To UBound(y)
        yi(i) = y(i)
    Next
    r = WorksheetFunction.Trend(y, x, Array(126))
    ri = WorksheetFunction.Trend(yi, xi, Array(126))
End Sub
```

Both results `r` and `ri` are Variant arrays of (1 to 1), with a Double item `r(1) = 67.7516453919795`

Comment: As far as I know the declaration of Dim value() As Integer produces an array, doesn't it? If I use the datatype variant for the array and use the above script to fill the arrays with values from the table that I retrieved via sql I am also getting an error.
"Unable to get Trend property of Worksheet function class." 
on line 
fnc_FMV = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(values, days, Array(liAge))(1)

Comment: The data you get from your database is probably not interpreted as a number. Try using a conversion like `CInt()` on your `lrs1.Fields()` statements.

Comment: days(iCounter) = CInt(lrs1.Fields("FMV_" & element))
is what I used for days and values. Still the same wrong results

Comment: Put a debug point and use the locals watch to determine that your array is being filled with the expected results?

Comment: I use the following to make sure the correct values are in the arrays "days" and "values"
Debug.Print days(0) & ", " & days(1) & ", " & days(2) & ", " & days(3) & ", " & days(4) & ", " & days(5) & ", " & days(6) & ", " & days(7) & ", " & days(8)
    Debug.Print values(0) & ", " & values(1) & ", " & values(2) & ", " & values(3) & ", " & values(4) & ", " & values(5) & ", " & values(6) & ", " & values(7) & ", " & values(8)
Thas is actually what drives me mad. All data is correct, but once I put it into the trend function it is somehow messed up

Comment: If I change my code to `x = Split("365, 548, 730, 913, 1095, 1278, 1460, 1643, 1825", ", ")` and `xi(i) = CInt(x(i))` then `r = WorksheetFunction.Trend(y, x, Array(126))` **fails** because the items are strings, and `ri = WorksheetFunction.Trend(yi, xi, Array(126))` gets a correct result.

Comment: What about the "Age" array? Try to put your arrays in a Watch as @Cody suggested, to see the actual values and data types. Also, try to find the problematic data. Put data you know to work instead of the arrays and items retrieved from the DB. Replace complete arrays, and then specific items, and focus the problem.

Comment: Hi @dePatinkin thank you for your continued support it is hugely appreciated. How do I go about to "put your arrays in a Watch"? I am not familiar with the concept of Watch. Thanks!

Comment: In the VBA editor you have a View>Watch window. Drag or add variables there.